# "Locking" a powerpoint document from user input while it is opened by my .NET program?

Tags: vba, vb.net, vsto, powerpoint

I am having a hard time finding an answer to my question because I do not know exactly how to word it concisely, so here is it is:

I would like my vb.net program to open a power point, flip through some slides for the user, and then close.  This is not an issue though, I can figure this out.  The thing I do not know if it is possible, is that while this is happening, I would like the open window to not respond to the user's input and to only respond to the program.  Mainly, I do not want the user to be able to change the slide themself.  Is this possible?  Is it also possible to change it so that at certain points the user can flip through the slides themself?  Are there options for the whole window not responding (you can't do ANYTHING, not even move it for example) versus only the page not turning (you could minimize or change size of the window)?

Thanks for whatever help you can give me on the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that the PowerPoint document needs to be visible? Perhaps you can make the PowerPoint instance invisible, then the user will not be able to interact...

Comment: I think @user1167662 wants it to be visible because he wants to flip some slides for his users

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Presentation ppt = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation;
ppt.SlideShowSettings.ShowType = PpSlideShowType.ppShowTypeKiosk;
ppt.SlideShowSettings.Run();
```

To be safer you can uncheck all settings in

File => Options => Advanced => Slide Show section